# How do I create a wheel from a django app?

Tags: python, django, setuptools

The reusable app docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/reusable-apps/) tells you to list template and static files in `MANIFEST.in`, but it doesn't look like `python setup.py bdist_wheel` looks at that file at all.

I've seen references to `data_files` but those files go in directories relative to the python installation (`sys.prefix`) and not the package installation (and `sys.prefix` isn't uniformly related to `site-packages` across systems).

Am I correct in assuming that `myapp/templates/myapp/foo.html` should end up in `.../site-packages/myapp/templates/myapp/foo.html` and similarly for static files, and that the user needs to run a `manage.py collectstatic` after `pip install myapp`?

Update (example):

The following structure:

```
(build2) go|c:\srv\tmp\myapp> tree
.
|-- MANIFEST.in
|-- myapp
|   |-- static
|   |   `-- myapp
|   |       `-- foo.css
|   |-- templates
|   |   `-- myapp
|   |       `-- foo.html
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- views.py
`-- setup.py

5 directories, 6 files
```

setup.py

```
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    name='myapp',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=['myapp']
)
```

MANIFEST.in

```
recursive-include myapp/templates *
recursive-include myapp/static *
```

running `python setup.py sdist` and `python setup.py bdist_wheel` creates the following files bin myapp/dist:

```
2016-06-18  13:47             2,073 myapp-0.1.0-py2-none-any.whl
2016-06-18  13:46             2,493 myapp-0.1.0.zip
```

if you look inside the .zip file, you'll find the templates and static folders, if you rename the .whl file to .zip and look inside it, the directories are not included.

**Update 2 (solution):**

Changing the MANIFEST.in file to

```
recursive-include myapp *
```

and setup.py to

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
setup(
    name='myapp',
    version='0.1.0',
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=['myapp'],
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

then running `python setup.py bdist_wheel` will create a `.whl` file that installs `myapp/templates` and `myapp/static` in the expected places.

Comment: can you show a MCSE of your problem? What have you tried within `MANIFEST.in` and `setup.py`?

Comment: @thebjorn, a pity about the bounty but you should probably answer your own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MANIFEST.in` file needs to be changed to:

```
recursive-include myapp *
```

This includes everything under `myapp/myapp` with the correct paths. In particular, this includes `myapp/myapp/templates`, which is necessary.

The declaration above also includes `myapp/myapp/static` which could be useful if you plan to run `manage.py collectstatic` after installing the `.whl` file.

In `setup.py`, the `setup` function needs to be imported from `setuptools` (and not distutils), i.e.:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
setup(
    name='myapp',
    version='0.1.0',
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=['myapp'],
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

When you now run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` it will create a `.whl` file that installs `myapp/templates` and `myapp/static` in the expected places.